# Обновление данных в Spring в реальном времени без бд

Tags: spring-boot

Всем привет! Извиняюсь за сумбурность/некоторой непоследовательности в повествовании, я только начинаю писать клиент серверные приложения java/spring + js/vue.js.
У меня имеется FileController в Spring. В нем написан метод как получить данные файла по его названию

```
@GetMapping("/get/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getFile(@PathVariable String fileName) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "/trajectories/" + fileName; // идет от папки resources

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(filePath);
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            String content = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("File not found");
        }
    }
```

на vue описана логика, что при вводе названия файла файл выгружается и его содержимое показывается в отдельном окошке.

Затем у меня реализована логика сохранения файла в Spring. файл сохраняется в resources/trajectories. И если открыть эту папку, файл с фронта правда сохраняется в эту папку. Но когда я с помощью GET запроса хочу получить данные вновь сохраненного файла, пишет что файл не найден. Но если перезагрузить сервер Spring, файл открывается с помощью GET запроса.
Как сделать так чтобы Spring мог обновлять свои ресурсы в реальном времени без необходимости перезапуска приложения